# Prestashop how to make modification on Add and Minus button in shopping cart

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

who knows what file controls the function for add and minus button in the shopping cart? I want to change the qty that is added or minus after any buttons is clicked.

this is the code for the ADD button

```
<a rel="nofollow" class="" id="" href="{$link->getPageLink('cart', true, NULL, "add=1&amp;id_product={$product.id_product|intval}&amp;ipa={$product.id_product_attribute|intval}&amp;id_address_delivery={$product.id_address_delivery|intval}&amp;token={$token_cart}")|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" title="{l s='Add' mod='advancedcheckout'}"><span><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span></a>
```

Changing `add=1` is not making any changes. So At start I thought it was a JS or AJAX file, but the button continues working even after I deleted all classes and ID. So I think all this trick is made by the code in `href=""`

But where I can make the changes for the qty added? Who knows?

Answer (score 0):

If I good understand. You should look at those file:

```
themes/defaylt-theme/js/product.js: line 424
themes/defaylt-theme/js/product.js: line 408
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the

> cart-summary.js

in your theme/js/ folder. This will contain the + and the - button events

> function upQuantity
>
> function downQuantity